# How to fill texture in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a shape and texture image.. (shape.png, texture.png)

I would like to paint a shape as texture.png pattern in cocos2d.
 (shape size is pretty bigger than texture image.
  so automatically fill texture pattern in entire shape.

I trying to know the way.

Can't find..

someone have a solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"texture.png"];

ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT};
[sprite.texture setTexParameters:&params];
[sprite setTextureRect: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, w, h)];
```

This code repeats a texture in both the x and the y (or s, t in texture terms). The only limitation is that your texture must be a power of two (ie. 64 * 128, 128 * 128, 1024 * 1024) etc.

Comment: Where indicate place as "texture.png" pattern?

Comment: The place where I put: `@"shape.png"`

Comment: I think Need "texture.png", don't you?