# Cocos2d v3 repeat texture

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, textures, repeat

I was wondering how I should repeat a texture in Cocos2d 3. I have a background and I want to “tile” it across the screen. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304968/how-to-fill-texture-in-cocos2d/7305017#7305017) which is using ccTexParams with GL_REPEAT but those have been made private in version 3 of cocos.

I have found another solution which can be [found here](http://www.nolithius.com/game-development/cocos2d-iphone-repeating-sprite) it creates a loop and positions a new child node based on the size of the texture and the size you want. But is that performant? Because when you have a 1px wide background texture and want to repeat that on a iPad retina, you have more than 2000 child nodes.

What is the best way to repeat a texture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well since there was no method for repeating without having a POT texture I made something of my own which takes care of it.

Might be useful for someone who has this same question. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/Matthijn/TiledSprite) on Github.

Comment: It seems that this class creates new sprites inside render:, it looks like it can get really heavy. Also it won't work with Cocos2D v3 because sprite batch nodes are gone.

Answer (score 0):

`CCTexture2D` class has `setTexParameters:` method to set repeat mode. Also pay attention that the texture must have power-of-two width and height, otherwise repeating mode will be disabled.

Comment: That is in version 2 and 1 if i'm correct. That method has been moved to CCTexture_Private.h (I could include that, but I was wondering why it has been made private).